# How to hide elements with React Native WebView

Tags: react-native, android-webview

Is there a way to hide elements of a source webpage using WebView in React Native? I am working to convert a web app that my company uses to complete meter replacements and make it available on mobile devices such as a phone and I need to hide some elements or certain toggles need to be disabled. I can show code if possible to better help explain. The source web app uses Angularjs

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a function on your web side in js which will perform these action when call.
Like write a function `toggleView` which contain your business logic.

You can pass some js code to `Webview` on start on webpage using `injectedJavaScript` prop.

So what you should have to do just write a JS code like below

```
const injectedJavaScript =
  (function() {
    toggleView();
    // other functions aswell
  })();
```

and pass this js to Webview like

```
<WebView
      source={{uri}}
      injectedJavaScript={injectedJavaScript}
    />
```

You can also communicate from your web to mobile app by passing

```
window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(event);
```

from web.

and now get this event in Webview prop `onMessage`

Comment: Got it, so that function needs to be on the actual web page, bit defined in web view. We currently do not own the site or have access to its code, but I would be able to do that in the Native app?

Comment: Then you can write that function (business logic) in your injectedJavaScript code aswell.